# Compare two lists on a condition and add to another list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Having two lists. First one is IEnumerable<dynamic> and other one is normal list. Need to compare them and on a certain condition I need to add them to new lists.

NormalList:

```
{
"List" :
{
"OuterID" : 1111,
"Name" : "Apple",
"Country" : "USA",
"InnerList" :{
              "InnerId" : 2222
             }
},
{
"OuterID" : 5555,
"Name" : "Mango",
"Country" : "INDIA",
"InnerList" :{
              "InnerId" : 7777
             }
}
```

Other list is IEnumerable<dynamic> received from db call

```
Resultlist
{
"OuterID" : 5555,
"InnerId" : 7777
}
```

Need to compare if the OuterID and InnerId are same. If yes, add them to MatchingList else add them to unmatching list

I have tried in simple C# like below. Is it possible to query using Linq to make it easier.

```
foreach(var list in NormalList)
{
int count = 0;
foreach(var res in ResultList)
{
 if(list.OuterID == (int)res.OuterID && list.InnerList.InnerId == (int)res.InnerId)
  {
      matchinglist.Add(list);
      count++;
  }
}
if(count == 0)
    unmatchinglist.Add(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the first loop by `Where` and the second by `Any`:

```cs
var matchinglist = NormalList.Where(
    n => ResultList.Any(r => n.OuterID == (int)r.OuterID && r.InnerList.InnerId == (int)r.InnerId)
).ToList();
var unmatchinglist = NormalList.Except(matchinglist).ToList();
```

As `unmatchinglist` is `NormalList` without the matching element. `Except` is a good fit here.